# Executing commands in mysqlsh using ansible playbooks

Tags: mysql, shell, yaml

I tried something like this snippet below, but the second task gets executed on the host's shell terminal, rather than the mysql shell. How do i execute commands on the opened mysqlsh in the first task?
Eg: i want to login to the shell and check the status of the mysql cluster.

```
tasks:
- name: "connect as clusteradmin"
shell: mysqlsh --uri admin@host1 -p'pass'
- name: "get cluster"
shell: var cluster=dba.getCluster('cluster')
- name: "check status of cluster"
shell: cluster.status()
register: Clustersts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to put your request into one line with parameter '--execute=command'.
Here is something which works for me:

`mysqlsh -uUSER -pPASSWORD -P 3306 --execute='util.checkForServerUpgrade()'`

Yours could look like as follows:

`- name: "connect as clusteradmin and get cluster"`

`shell: mysqlsh --uri admin@host1 -p'pass' --execute='var cluster=dba.getCluster('cluster')'`

and then:

`- name: "connect as clusteradmin and check status of cluster"`

`shell: mysqlsh --uri admin@host1 -p'pass' --execute='cluster.status()'`